# ¿Cómo cerrar la ventana actual?

Tags: python, windows, tkinter, python-2.x

Buenas compañeros, quiero hacer algo similar a un cajero automático, mi problema es que cuando quiero cerrar la segunda ventana con `withdraw()` me dice que no esta definida esa ventana, si la defino abre un cuadro sin nada, parte del código es este.

```
import tkinter as tk

from tkinter import messagebox

def validar():

        if entrada1.get()=="1234": 
            Opciones()
        else:
            messagebox.showwarning('PIN Invalido', 'PIN incorrecto')



def Opciones():

    ventana.withdraw() 
    ventana2=tk.Toplevel() 
    ventana2.geometry('380x300+0+0')
    ventana2.configure(background='grey')
    ventana2.title("Ventana 2")
    e3=tk.Label(ventana,text="Que operacion desea realizar",bg="blue",fg="white")
    e3.pack(padx=5,pady=5,ipadx=5,ipady=5,fill=tk.X)
    boton2=tk.Button(ventana2,text="OK" , command=cerrarventana)
    boton2.pack(side=tk.TOP)
    botondeposito=tk.Button(ventana2,text="Retiro", command=abrirretiro)
    botondeposito.pack(side=tk.TOP)


def abrirretiro():

    ***ventana2.withdraw()#*** aqui no se que hacer para cerrar esta ventana

    ventana3=tk.Toplevel() #ventana emergente
    ventana3.geometry('380x300+0+0')
    ventana3.configure(background='grey')
    ventana3.title("Ventana 3")
    e4=tk.Label(ventana3,text="Elija cuanto desea Retirar",bg="blue",fg="white")
    e4.pack(padx=5,pady=5,ipadx=5,ipady=5,fill=tk.X)
    boton4=tk.Button(ventana3,text="1000" , command=Opciones)
    boton4.pack(side=tk.TOP)
    botonvolver=tk.Button(ventana2,text="Volver" , command=Opciones)
    botonvolver.pack(side=tk.TOP)

ventana=tk.Tk()

ventana.title('Ventana1')

ventana.geometry('380x300+0+0')

ventana.configure(background='grey') 


e1=tk.Label(ventana,text='PIN',bg='green',fg='white')

e1.pack(padx=5,pady=5,ipadx=5,ipady=5)

entrada1=tk.Entry(ventana)

entrada1.pack(fill=tk.X,padx=5,pady=5,ipadx=5,ipady=5)  

boton3=tk.Button(ventana,text="Validar PIN",fg="blue",command=validar)

boton3.pack(side=tk.TOP)  

ventana.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que `ventana2` es una variable local solo accesible desde la función `Opciones`. Sin tener en cuenta opciones dentro de la programación orientada a objetos, para poder acceder a ella desde `abrirretiro` debe ser una variable global.

Podrías declarar las variables `ventana2` y `ventana3` como globales y con valor `None`, luego usar la palabra reservada `global` en las funciones para indicar que se use la variable global en vez de crearla.

No obstante, ten en cuenta que **`withdraw` no destruye la ventana**, solo la oculta. Por tanto puedes simplemente crear todas las ventanas cuando creas la ventana principal y usar las funciones solo para ocultar/mostrar las que te interesen en cada momento con `withdraw`/`deiconify` y realizar las operaciones:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox


def validar():
        if entrada1.get()=="1234": 
            Opciones()
        else:
            messagebox.showwarning('PIN Invalido', 'PIN incorrecto')

def Opciones():
    ventana.withdraw()
    ventana2.deiconify()
    ventana3.withdraw()

def abrirretiro():
    ventana2.withdraw()
    ventana3.deiconify()

def cerrarventana():
    pass



ventana=tk.Tk()
ventana.title('Ventana1')
ventana.geometry('380x300+0+0')
ventana.configure(background='grey') 
e1=tk.Label(ventana,text='PIN',bg='green',fg='white')
e1.pack(padx=5,pady=5,ipadx=5,ipady=5)
entrada1=tk.Entry(ventana)
entrada1.pack(padx=5,pady=5,ipadx=5,ipady=5)
btn = tk.Button(ventana, text = "Aceptar", command=validar)
btn.pack(padx=5,pady=5,ipadx=5,ipady=5)

ventana2 = tk.Toplevel()
ventana2.geometry('380x300+0+0')
ventana2.configure(background='grey')
ventana2.title("Ventana 2")
e3=tk.Label(ventana2,text="Que operacion desea realizar",bg="blue",fg="white")
e3.pack(padx=5,pady=5,ipadx=5,ipady=5,fill=tk.X)
boton2=tk.Button(ventana2,text="OK" , command=cerrarventana)
boton2.pack(side=tk.TOP)
botondeposito=tk.Button(ventana2,text="Retiro", command=abrirretiro)
botondeposito.pack(side=tk.TOP)
ventana2.withdraw()

ventana3 = tk.Toplevel()
ventana3.geometry('380x300+0+0')
ventana3.configure(background='grey')
ventana3.title("Ventana 3")
e4=tk.Label(ventana3,text="Elija cuanto desea Retirar",bg="blue",fg="white")
e4.pack(padx=5,pady=5,ipadx=5,ipady=5,fill=tk.X)
boton4=tk.Button(ventana3,text="1000" , command=Opciones)
boton4.pack(side=tk.TOP)
botonvolver=tk.Button(ventana3,text="Volver" , command=Opciones)
botonvolver.pack(side=tk.TOP)
ventana3.withdraw()

ventana.mainloop()
```

Otra opción sin usar variables globales es pasar a la función `abrirretiro` la instancia de `ventana2` desde `Opciones` como argumento:

```
from functools import partial


def Opciones():
    ventana.withdraw() 
    ventana2=tk.Toplevel() 
    ventana2.geometry('380x300+0+0')
    ventana2.configure(background='grey')
    ventana2.title("Ventana 2")
    e3=tk.Label(ventana2,text="Que operacion desea realizar",bg="blue",fg="white")
    e3.pack(padx=5,pady=5,ipadx=5,ipady=5,fill=tk.X)
    boton2=tk.Button(ventana2,text="OK" , command=cerrarventana)
    boton2.pack(side=tk.TOP)
    botondeposito=tk.Button(ventana2,text="Retiro", command=partial(abrirretiro, ventana2))
    botondeposito.pack(side=tk.TOP)


def abrirretiro(ventana2):
    ventana2.withdraw()
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, me fue de gran ayuda